# Replace function error trying to export file with odbc

Tags: sql, replace

```
select id, "last name", "first name", address, "zip code", "Home phone", "Mobile Phone",
REPLACE([email address],',','') as email, "date of birth",
iif ( len([recall date]) = 3,
left("recall date",1)+'/01/20'+ right("recall date",2),
left("recall date",2)+'/01/20'+ right("recall date",2))
as Recalldate
from "patient information"
```

Im trying to **replace** a comma that is at the end of each email address somehow its coming from access.

The current query is causing an error 
9/18/2014 7:11:01 PM error System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException : ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Extra ) in query expression '[left([Email address])'.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the provider that you are using for querying the table(s), the functions `Replace`, `IIF`, `Len`, `Left` and `Right` might not be available or have different meaning.  Without any details on how this query is executed, from where and against with what type of database that you are doing this, it's impossible to tell you what the error might be and how to correct it.

One possibility would be to replace the single quote with double quotes as in:

```
Replace([email address],",","")
```

but this is only a guess. You don't seem to have any problem later in your query expression with single quotes; so I don't think that this is the problem in your case.  I showing this just to give you an example of what kind of stuff can go wrong when using different providers or different databases.

I've also noticed that sometimes, you use the `[...]` to delimit your field names and other times, you use the double quotes `"..."`.  Not a good ideal to mix this kind of stuff as some providers will accept one notation but not the others.

Finally, by experience, I can tell you that using any space in a field or a table name such as `"patient information"` is a very, very bad idea.  Stop doing that or later, you might deeply regret it when you will query your database from a system that doesn't or badly support that type of stuff.

Comment: SylvainL I agree that the use of spaces in field names is a disaster. The customer created this database and I am trying to export data from it, so i am not allowed to change his table/field names. I Will try that double quotes and see what happens.

Comment: Replace() is usually a VBA function and is usually not available in the backend database.  However, you can often use it in a Select query under Access against a database because Access will first run your query without the call to the Replace() function and then will apply it locally to the returned resultset; giving you the impression that this function is available and running on the underlying database.  Same thing apply to other functions like IIF(). However, this possibility is not always available; depending on your programming and what you are doing.

Comment: i tried your recommendation but it still didnt work. I think i found a posting that says Replace only works on vba 6.05 i am unsure which version the client is on. So now i am waiting for his response.